# Deleting Data for HABTM in cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

i am a new beginner in cakephp. I am trying to do a deletion based on HABTM relationship, but failed. Please help me.

I have three tables: `products`, `users` and `users_products` table.

one product can have many users and one user will have many products. The structure of users_products table is : `id`, `user_id`, `product_id`, `renew_id`.

I want to delete all datas in `users_products` and `products` table when `renew_id` meet certain condition, but i do not want to touch anything on the `users` table.

I am thinking to write a while loop to delete the records, but afraid will cause many queries and not using cakephp features.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

For Has Many and HABTM data deletion we prefer this method

```
//delete(int $id = null, boolean $cascade = true);
  $this->Product->delete($id,true);
```

Cascade will work only when the relationship is defined in Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows from the join just like any other model.

`$this->UsersProduct->delete()` or `$this->UsersProduct->deleteAll()`

If you are using HABTM that relation might not be available so you can define the relations in the models such as User hasMany UsersProduct and Product hasMany UsersProduct, that would allow access from both sides.

You can also use `ClassRegistry::init('UsersProduct')->deleteAll()`

As a side note, your join model is incorrectly named as it should be ProductsUser based on the conventions, that is join tables are alphabetical order of the join models. Following conventions would give you a table called `products_users`